# req.cookies returns [Object: null prototype] {} in only Post request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, axios, jwt

I'm trying to implement authentication with jwt in nodejs and frontend reactjs. I send the accessToken in the response when user login. And them I test the cookies with two end points. First end point is Get method and the second is Post method. After calling the first end point with **GET** method server response the cookie well but the second end point with **Post** method response 'Object: null prototype] {}'.

*Creating Secure Cookie with refresh token*

```
res.cookie('jwt', refreshToken, { 
      httpOnly: true, 
      secure: true, 
      sameSite: 'None', 
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
     })
```

*frontend code for GET method*

```
const testCookiesGetMethod = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.get('auth/test',{ 
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
        });
    }
```

*Server side code for GET Request*

```
export const testGet = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.cookies);
}
```

*Output for GET Method*

```
{
jwt: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InllbGxvdyIsImlhdCI6MTY2OTM1NjYxMiwiZXhwIjoxNjY5NDQzMDEyfQ.5cibdr1bboyNf3p4fUXkp4nVO3SE2lPi_h5FUBrzqjE'
}
```

*frontend code for POST method*

```
const testCookiesPostMethod = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post('auth/test',{ 
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
        });
    }
```

*server side code for POST request*

```
export const testPost = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.cookies);
}
```

*output for POST Method*

```
[Object: null prototype] {}
```

Comment: Are you using cookie parser middleware in node express or not ?

Comment: Or try to add credentials : true and origin:true in your cors middleware

Comment: Have you set up `proxy` in your frontend's `package.json` ?

Comment: @huzaifac137 Yes Sir! I already added cookie parser middleware and credential:true. I want to know cookie can pass only in GET method?

Comment: @Aleksandar Yes Sir! Already set up.

Comment: thanks... I was getting the same error but in my case I was forgetting this: 

`withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you are using the `post` Axios shorthand method the second argument has to be the `data` you want to send to the server, and in the third argument you pass the `options` object:

```
const testCookiesPostMethod = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post('auth/test', 
            {}, //here a data to be sent
            { 
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

set

```
 secure: false
```

in development mode.